# Tying to upload a patch for review, but i keep getting a credential error

Tags: git, github, dart

I have git cl involved, and the local branch i created off of master is committed and ready to go.  The next step according to online (https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/wiki/Contributing) says to do:  `git cl upload -s` but it returns the error:

```
Credentials for the following hosts are required:
  github-review.com
  github.com
These are read from /Users/fallenreaper/.gitcookies (or legacy 
/Users/fallenreaper/.netrc)
You can (re)generate your credentials by visiting https://github-
review.com/new-password
```

but that website doesnt exist.  When i looked online, i then went to: https://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/developer-guide/gerrit-guide because it seems that gets me closer.  I followed that and it set up the right files, but when i then followed it up with the previous command, `git cl upload -s` it doesnt push.

Is there something I am doing wrong to get this to push to Dart-Lang for Code Review?  I am trying to push patch an issue I created, had some discussion about, and have been watching for a year now.

Answer (score 2):

Try running `git remote -v` which should give you an output like this:

```
origin  https://dart.googlesource.com/sdk.git (fetch)
origin  https://dart.googlesource.com/sdk.git (push)
```

That is, if you [checked out the code](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/wiki/Building#getting-the-source) with `fetch dart` rather than `git clone` and the GitHub repository URL. If you see a GitHub URL, the simplest solution is to create a new checkout with `fetch dart` and apply your changes there. `git cl upload` will then give you the correct URL to Dart's Gerrit host: https://dart-review.googlesource.com/new-password